# Mock IDataRecord using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, mocking, moq

I am attempting to Mock an IDataRecord interface.

So far I have:

```
        var mockIDataRecord = new Mock<IDataRecord>();
        mockIDataRecord.SetupGet(c => c["id"]).Returns(7);
        var z = mockIDataRecord["id"];
```

But Visual Studio throws a compilation error on the last line of that:

Error   2   Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Moq.Mock <System.Data.IDataRecord>'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is what visual studio says. You are applying indexing to instance of `Mock` class, not its generic parameter (`IDataRecord` in your case). Use `Mock.Object` Property that will return IDataRecord and apply indexing to it

```
var z = mockIDataRecord.Object["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a mock of an object (of type IDataRecord). However you are trying to access mockIDataRecord[id] which implies that mockIDataRecord is a collection (Array?).

The type mismatch is probably what is causing the error.

Can you try something like this instead (I haven't checked the syntax):

```
var mockIDataRecord = new Mock<IDataRecord[]>();
```